Return signal and subscribe to it in Angular
I currently have this piece of code. I'm using signals, because I understand that's the newest way to achieve what I'm trying to achieve, rather than using an observable, or toPromise(), which is deprecated. And I also understand that using async/await syntax is not the way to go about this.
entryArray$ = signal<Entry[]>([]);

getEntryBatch(lemma?: string): Entry[] {
    if (lemma) {
      this.httpClient
        .get<Entry[]>(`${this.url}/entries/l/${lemma}`)
        .subscribe((response) => {
          this.entryArray$.set(response);
          console.log(this.entryArray$()) // this logs the expected response
        });
      console.log(this.entryArray$()); // this runs too early
    } else {
      console.log('error catching lemma');
    }
    console.log(this.entryArray$()); // this runs too early
    return this.entryArray$();
  }

When I call the function as follows, I don't get the expected response:
this.resultEntries$.set(
      this.entriesService.getEntryBatch(this.searchService.mySearch().letter),
    );

I've tried changing .subscribe((res) => ... to .pipe(map((res) =>((res) =>... because that's what some threads suggest I should be doing in a case like this, but couldn't make it work either. My understanding is that what I need to achieve is for the function getEntryBatch to return a signal, and then subscribe to the signal when I call the function with getEntryBatch(...).subscribe() but I can't make any of this work.

Signals Approach:
Try to use effect to trigger the data refresh.
effect(() => {
    this.entriesService.getEntryBatch(this.searchService.mySearch().letter).subscribe();
});

Then use a getter to access the signal from the service in the component.
get resultEntries$() {
    return this.entriesService.entryArray$;
}

Then you can rewrite the service to.
entryArray$ = signal<Entry[]>([]);

getEntryBatch(lemma?: string): Observable<Entry[]> {
      return (lemma ? this.httpClient
        .get<Entry[]>(`${this.url}/entries/l/${lemma}`) : of([]))
        .pipe(tap((response) => {
          this.entryArray$.set(response);
        });
  }


Observable Approach:
You can use toObservable to convert the signal to an observable, which will react to changes in the source signal
entryArray$ = toObservable(this.searchService.mySearch()).pipe(
    switchMap((mySearch: any) => this.entriesService.getEntryBatch(mySearch.letter)),
);

In the HTML, we can use async pipe ( From JSmith answer )
for( result of entryArray$ | async; track $index ) {
   ...
}


@ŽigaGrošelj http requests are auto unsubscribed, official documentation reference

@ŽigaGrošelj please delete the comment , thanks!

You could do something like that. toSignal expects an observable and subscribes to it, if not used in injection context, this means in constructor or in top level, you also need to pass injector.
resultEntries$ = toSignal(this.httpClient
    .get<Entry[]>(`${this.url}/entries/l/${lemma}`)) 

As for you, you could move what is inside toSignal to a method, and do something like that:
resultEntries$ = toSignal(getEntryBatch('lemma')) 

getEntryBatch():Observable<Entry[]>{
 // implementation of api call here, without subscribe, you should return observable.
}

